# Разбор массива $_REQUEST

Tags: php, mysql, sql, массивы

возникла проблема следующего характера:
Присутствует следующий url:

http://test.loc/?&days[]=10&days[]=25&days[]=34&rcount[]=100&rcount[]=200&rcount[]=300&dst[]=8707530&dst[]=87074444&dst[]=523523&id=355

id = не нужно учитывать, брать из массива только days, dst, rcount

```
  <?
 echo '<pre>';
 var_dump($_REQUEST);
 ?>
```

[image: Array]

Вопрос, мне нужно как-то разобрать $_REQUEST и делать INSERT в таблицу.

Записи должны быть следующие:
[image: Таблица]
Как разобрать данный массив? Необходимо делать инсерт в базу по одинаковым ключам, т.е. days[0], rcount[0], dst[0]  и т.д.
В целом ,как я понимаю, в итоге должен быть следующий код:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`days`,`rcount`,`dst`) VALUES ('$array['days']','$array['rcount']','$array['dst']')
```

Спасибо за помощь! Надеюсь объяснил понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из общего прилетевшего массива, пусть это будет `$array` - берем нужные массивы.
Так-как, ключи всех массивов соответствуют друг-другу, перебираем массив дней и вытаскиваем из остальных массивов по ключу дней - самый простой вариант:

```
$days = $array['days'];
$rcount = $array['rcount'];
$dst = $array['dst'];
foreach($days as $key => $day) {
    $rc = $rcount[$key];
    $dt = $dst[$key];
    echo $day,
         ' ',
         $rc,
         ' ',
         $dt,
        '<br>';
}
```

Вывод:

```
10 100 8707530
25 200 87074444
34 300 523523
```

Ну а в запрос думаю не затруднитесь добавить переменные.
И желательно использовать подготавливаемые запросы `PDO` или `MYSQLI`, а то так, можно будет взломать вашу базу.